# In YII2, how can I show some notifications counter in the lable

Tags: menu, notifications, label, yii2, nav

Suppose I have a label like: 
`['label' => 'Notifications','url'=>['notifications/index']],`
which I'm using to show nav menu.

Now how I can show some notifications counter(like badge) beside the menu?

I used it in the button by:

```
echo"<button id='new_data' name='New data' class='btn btn-default'>New Data<sup><font color='red' size='4'><b>".$new_data_number."</b></font></sup></button>";
```

where *$new_data_number* is the number to show in the notification. Now I want to show the number in the menu.

> As I can't give any comment,I edited the question.Here is my code:

In the component/MenueHelper.php file:

```
public static function getLowermenu()
  {
    $role_name = \Yii::$app->session->get('usertypename');
    $result    = static::getLowerRecrusive($role_name);
    return $result;
  }

private static function getLowerRecrusive($parent)
  {
    $result = [];
    $counter = 10;
    if($parent == 'Admin')
    {
      $result =
      [
        ['label' => 'Users', 'url' => ['users/index']],
        ['label' => '<span class="pull-right badge">10</span> New Arrivals', 'icon' => 'home'],
      ];
      return $result
```

Now in the layout file: 
`<?php
        echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'right'],
        'items' => app\components\MenuHelper::getLowermenu(),
           ]);
      ?>`

 Its ok for the first label(*Users*), but for the second one(*New Arrival*), its showing the html code also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
['label' => 'Notifications' .$new_data_number,'url'=>['notifications/index']],
```

and for the second question try

```
['label' =>  '<span class="badge">'.$new_data_number .'</span>'
```

Comment: actually it partially solved my problem, now its showing the $new_data_number beside the link, but I need some think like the *badge*  from the bootstrap: `<span class="badge">$new_data_number</span>`

Comment: I have update the answer.   Basically you have to dynamically compose the string to associate with the label

Comment: Sorry, it's not showing the notification things, it's showing the whole html code. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: check the ' and " character sequence or post all your actual menu code.